# Learning jQuery selectors. How to alert the value of the selector?

Tags: jquery

Take this code for example:

```
$('.photo').hover(
            function() {
                //display heading and caption
                $(this).children('div:first').stop(true,false).animate({top:0},{duration:200, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
                $(this).children('div:last').stop(true,false).animate({bottom:0},{duration:200, easing: 'easeOutQuart'})
})
```

Lets say I want to know which element was selected with this line:

```
$(this).children('div:first')
```

Is it possible somehow to alert the targeted element? I tried:

```
something = $(this).children('div:first').val();
                alert (something);
```

or

```
something = $(this).children('div:first');
                alert (something);
```

With the first example I get blank alert. With second - Objext object.

Regards,

Comment: You simply need to use console.log instead of alert. You can then even hover the result in console and it will show where that element is on the page.

Comment: This should give you what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: What would you like you alert to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
something = $(this).children('div:first').text();
                alert (something);
```

or

```
something = $(this).children('div:first').html();
                alert (something);
```

Comment: This gives you the inner Html/text not the whole element html.

Comment: What if the element doesn't have any content? This will be useless.

Comment: I see Esailijas point with no element but .html() was just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Of course! you can use console.log which works great with jQuery selections.

```
console.log($(this).children('div:first'));
```

if you're using firefox or chrome, press F12 to open your developer's console, navigate to the console tab, and you will see your entire selection and structures.

This is highly useful for also showing arrays and objects, and anything, in fact!